# how to set vm- arguments in application server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jvm-arguments

I have deployed a servlet in orion application server. This servlet is making call to third party library. In eclipse I used set this library path in VM arguments tab. But after deploying in application server Ihave no idea where to add VM-Arguments. Can any one please help me?

Thanks in Advance..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the extra VM arguments on the startup command using:
`java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -DanotherVmArg=somevalue -jar orion.jar -userThreads`

I think the Orion server does not have a configuration script to set-up extra VM arguments.
In case it does have it - you should specify it there and have a "clean" startup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the orion server, but with e.g. Apache Tomcat you'd pack your third party library into your WEB-INF/lib folder and have it deployed along with the rest of your web application. Jars in that lib folder are automatically in the classpath of your application so there'd be no need to set any extra arguments.